# Issues with converting time values to 24-hour format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the following Apps Script:

```
// Process each original column
function moveColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var startIndex = 40; // The starting column (AN)
  var columnsCount = 7; // The number of columns in the specified range
  var columnsToAdd = 28; // The number of columns to create to the right
  var startIndexNewColumns = 53; // The starting new column (BB)

  // Add 28 columns after the last column
  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(lastColumn, columnsToAdd);

  // Retrieve originalHeader values from the first cell in columns AN:AT
  var originalHeaderRange = sheet.getRange(1, startIndex, 1, columnsCount);
  var originalHeaderValues = originalHeaderRange.getValues()[0];


  // Process each original column
  for (var i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
    var originalHeader = originalHeaderValues[i];


    // Place headers for the new columns with prefixes
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 1).setValue(originalHeader + "_opening1");
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 2).setValue(originalHeader + "_closing1");
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 3).setValue(originalHeader + "_opening2");
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 4).setValue(originalHeader + "_closing2");

    // Process each cell in the original column
    var originalColumn = sheet.getRange(2, startIndex + i, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

    for (var j = 0; j < originalColumn.length; j++) {
      var cellValue = originalColumn[j][0] + ""; // Convert to string
      cellValue = cellValue.trim();

      // Get the time values from the original script
      var timeValues = cellValue.split(',').map(function (time) {
        return time.trim();
      });

      // Check if the cell has a comma (two time values)
      if (timeValues.length > 1) {
        // Split each time value by en dash and trim
        var time1 = timeValues[0].split('–').map(function (time) {
          return time.trim();
        });
        var time2 = timeValues[1].split('–').map(function (time) {
          return time.trim();
        });

        // Place the values in the corresponding new columns
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 1).setValue(time1[0]); // opening1
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 2).setValue(time1[1] || ""); // closing1
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 3).setValue(time2[0]); // opening2
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 4).setValue(time2[1] || ""); // closing2

        // Time values placed in new columns
      } else {
        // No comma, treat it as a single time value
        var hyphenSplit = cellValue.split('–').map(function (time) {
          return time.trim();
        });

        // Place the values in the corresponding new columns
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 1).setValue(hyphenSplit[0]); // opening1
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 2).setValue(hyphenSplit[1] || ""); // closing1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a sample of the output of the script.

| Monday_opening1 | Monday_closing1 | Monday_opening2 | Monday_closing2 | Tuesday_opening1 | Tuesday_closing1 | Tuesday_opening2 | Tuesday_closing2 | Wednesday_opening1 | Wednesday_closing1 | Wednesday_opening2 | Wednesday_closing2 | Thursday_opening1 | Thursday_closing1 | Thursday_opening2 | Thursday_closing2 | Friday_opening1 | Friday_closing1 | Friday_opening2 | Friday_closing2 | Saturday_opening1 | Saturday_closing1 | Saturday_opening2 | Saturday_closing2 | Sunday_opening1 | Sunday_closing1 | Sunday_opening2 | Sunday_closing2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4:30 | 8:00 PM |  |  | 4:30 | 8:00 PM |  |  | 4:30 | 8:00 PM |  |  | 4:30 | 8:00 PM |  |  | 4:30 | 8:00 PM |  |  | 4:30 | 8:00 PM |  |  | 4:30 | 8:00 PM |  |  |
| Closed |  |  |  | 5 | 10:30 PM |  |  | 5 | 10:30 PM |  |  | 5 | 10:30 PM |  |  | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 2:30 PM | 5 | 11:00 PM | Closed |  |  |  |
| Closed |  |  |  | Closed |  |  |  | 3:30 | 9:30 PM |  |  | 3:30 | 9:30 PM |  |  | 3:30 | 9:30 PM |  |  | 3:30 | 9:30 PM |  |  | Closed |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Closed |  |  |  | Closed |  |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  |
| Closed |  |  |  | 12 | 9:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 9:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 4 | 10:00 PM |  |  | Closed |  |  |  |
| Closed |  |  |  | Closed |  |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5:30 | 11:00 PM |  |  |
| 11:30 AM | 11:00 PM |  |  | 11:30 AM | 11:00 PM |  |  | 11:30 AM | 11:00 PM |  |  | 11:30 AM | 11:00 PM |  |  | 11:30 AM | 12:00 AM |  |  | 11:30 AM | 12:00 AM |  |  | 11:30 AM | 11:00 PM |  |  |
| 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  |
| 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 11:00 AM | 10:00 PM |  |  | 11:00 AM | 9:30 PM |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 12 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 12:00 PM | 12:00 AM |  |  | 12:00 PM | 12:00 AM |  |  | 12 | 10:00 PM |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11:30 AM | 2:30 PM | 5:30 | 9:30 PM | 11:30 AM | 2:30 PM | 5:30 | 10:00 PM | 11:30 AM | 2:30 PM | 5:30 | 10:00 PM | 11:30 AM | 2:30 PM | 5:30 | 11:00 PM | 11:30 AM | 2:30 PM | 5:30 | 11:00 PM | 5 | 11:00 PM |  |  | 11:30 AM | 3:00 PM | 5:30 | 9:30 PM |

From here on, I want to convert the time values to a 24-hour format.

As can be seen in the table provided, in opening1 and opening2 columns, there are time values that are of a single didgit and lack the AM/PM period. In these cases, I want to use the period of the cell to the right, since it is the same period the cell with the missing period should have. I also want to add two digits to both hours and minutes. To achieve this, I have tried the following:

```
// Process each original column
function moveColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var startIndex = 40; // The starting column (AN)
  var columnsCount = 7; // The number of columns in the specified range
  var columnsToAdd = 28; // The number of columns to create to the right
  var startIndexNewColumns = 53; // The starting new column (BB)

  // Add 28 columns after the last column
  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(lastColumn, columnsToAdd);

  // Retrieve originalHeader values from the first cell in columns AN:AT
  var originalHeaderRange = sheet.getRange(1, startIndex, 1, columnsCount);
  var originalHeaderValues = originalHeaderRange.getValues()[0];

  // Process each original column
  for (var i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
    var originalHeader = originalHeaderValues[i];

    // Place headers for the new columns with prefixes
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 1).setValue(originalHeader + "_opening1");
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 2).setValue(originalHeader + "_closing1");
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 3).setValue(originalHeader + "_opening2");
    sheet.getRange(1, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 4).setValue(originalHeader + "_closing2");

    // Process each cell in the original column
    var originalColumn = sheet.getRange(2, startIndex + i, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

    for (var j = 0; j < originalColumn.length; j++) {
      var cellValue = originalColumn[j][0] + ""; // Convert to string
      cellValue = cellValue.trim();

      // Get the time values from the original script
      var timeValues = cellValue.split(',').map(function (time) {
        return time.trim();
      });

      // Check if the cell has a comma (two time values)
      if (timeValues.length > 1) {
        // Split each time value by en dash and trim
        var time1 = timeValues[0].split('–').map(function (time) {
          return time.trim();
        });
        var time2 = timeValues[1].split('–').map(function (time) {
          return time.trim();
        });

        // Convert time values to 24-hour format
        time1[0] = convertTo24HourFormat(time1[0], time1[1]);
        time1[1] = convertTo24HourFormat(time1[1], time2[0]);
        time2[0] = convertTo24HourFormat(time2[0], time2[1]);
        time2[1] = convertTo24HourFormat(time2[1], "");

        // Place the values in the corresponding new columns
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 1).setValue(time1[0]); // opening1
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 2).setValue(time1[1] || ""); // closing1
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 3).setValue(time2[0]); // opening2
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 4).setValue(time2[1] || ""); // closing2

        // Time values placed in new columns
      } else {
        // No comma, treat it as a single time value
        var hyphenSplit = cellValue.split('–').map(function (time) {
          return time.trim();
        });

        // Convert time value to 24-hour format
        hyphenSplit[0] = convertTo24HourFormat(hyphenSplit[0], hyphenSplit[1]);
        hyphenSplit[1] = convertTo24HourFormat(hyphenSplit[1], "");

        // Place the values in the corresponding new columns
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 1).setValue(hyphenSplit[0]); // opening1
        sheet.getRange(j + 2, startIndexNewColumns + i * 4 + 2).setValue(hyphenSplit[1] || ""); // closing1
      }
    }
  }
}

// Function to convert time value to 24-hour format
function convertTo24HourFormat(time, period) {
  if (!time) return "";

  var timeParts = time.split(":");
  var hours = parseInt(timeParts[0]);
  var minutes = parseInt(timeParts[1]);

  if (period) {
    if (period.toLowerCase() === "pm" && hours < 12) {
      hours += 12;
    } else if (period.toLowerCase() === "am" && hours === 12) {
      hours = 0;
    }
  }

  return padZero(hours) + ":" + padZero(minutes);
}

// Function to pad zero to single-digit numbers
function padZero(number) {
  return number < 10 ? "0" + number : number;
}
```

Unfortunately, this returns NaN values which are obviously not desired. When I modify the `convertTo24HourFormat` function to avoid NaN values, I get empty strings which is also an undesired output. My question is, how can I achieve the desired output which should look like that of the following table:

| Monday_opening1 | Monday_closing1 | Monday_opening2 | Monday_closing2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11:30 | 14:30 | 17:30 | 21:30 | two time ranges |
| 11:30 | 14:30 |  |  | one time range |

Answer (score 1):

You can use setNumberFormat("HH:mm:ss");//for 24 hour format